# How to access SQLite from JavaScript in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, sqlite, dygraphs

I am trying to build a web-app using Django where I take in a stream of csv data, write a Python script to upload the data to the local SQLite database, then later connect to the database and use that data to build a JS-based graph.

Currently, I am trying to do this:

```
from .models import GraphData
def getdata(request):
    return JsonResponse({'graphdata': GraphData})
```

And the JavaScript is:

```
var dataxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
dataxhttp.open("GET", "/testGraph/getdata/", true); //this is where I try to connect to the URL that gets the data
        dataxhttp.send();
        var j = 0;
        dataxhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (dataxhttp.readyState == 4 && (dataxhttp.status == 200 || dataxhttp.status == 0)) {
                console.log("Ready state: " + dataxhttp.readyState);
                console.log("Status: " + dataxhttp.status);
                console.log(dataxhttp.response); // Not working, unless I change {'graphdata': GraphData} to {'graphdata': GraphData.objects.get(id=1).customerName}
            }
        }
```

The way I want to use it is this way:

```
data = dataxhttp.response;
console.log(data.get(id=1).customerName);
```

or:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    console.log(data.get(id=i).customerName;
}
```

Also, is it possible to access 'dataxhttp.response' or 'data' outside 'dataxhttp.onreadystatechange()'? This way, I can get the data inside 'readystatechange' then use it outside to build my graph.

Comment: if you make an assignment to a variable in your xhttp response data that should work to access outside the response call itself. However you can't of course truly use/show any data until you have some, i.e. the response is ready.

Comment: You cannot "execute" python functions in JS. There are two ways to achieve something similar to what you want - return all rows from django and then iterate over it in JS or make graph api on django side and use something like you want.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I solved this problem thanks to some combination of your suggestions.